# Kohana 3.x ORM has_many through delete relationship

Tags: orm, kohana, relationship, has-many

I Have three tables, contact, list and listmembers. Contacts from contact table are associated to lists from list table via listmembers table.

```
class Model_Contact extends ORM{
        protected $_has_many = array(
                'lists'=>array('model'=>'List', 'through'=>'listmembers', 'far_key'=>'dlid', 'foreign_key'=>'uid')
        );
}

class Model_List extends ORM
{

        protected $_has_many = array(
                'contacts'=>array('model'=>'Contact', 'through'=>'listmembers', 'far_key'=>'uid', 'foreign_key'=>'dlid')
        );
}
```

I have to update contact and list relationship in listmemebers table 
- create new relationship between existing contact and existing list
- Remove relationship between contact and list
How can I achieve this in Kohana ORM? I can always create model for listmembers and directly add/delete on this model. But is there a way to handle via relationship without creating listmembers model?

Answer (score 1):

I think the documentation explains it quite well: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/orm/relationships#hasmany-through